# How to reset error message after button has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I'm working on a mock pet adoption site. Super simple layout and functionality except for one issue. I have an error message that comes up when the 'submit' button is pressed and the user tries to submit a pet for adoption without clicking the 'terms and conditions' box. The error comes up, but if I click the button again (without checking the terms and conditions check box), it's like the error just appends another error message.

I am trying to get it where it won't create another error message. I have tried setting the alertMessage variable to an empty string at the end of the function in hopes of it resetting itself, but this does not work.

Thank you in advance for all of your help.

```
$('#add-pet').on('click', function() {

  if (termsBox.checked) {
  // Grab info from the form
  let $name = $('#pet-name');
  let $species = $('#pet-species');
  let $notes = $('#pet-notes');

  // Assemble the HTML of our new element with the above variables
  let $newPet = $(
    '<section class="six columns"><div class="card"><p><strong>Name:</strong> ' + $name.val() +
    '</p><p><strong>Species:</strong> ' + $species.val() + 
    '</p><p><strong>Notes:</strong> ' + $notes.val() + 
    '</p><span class="close">&times;</span></div></section>'
  );
  // Attach the element to the page
  $('#posted-pets').append($newPet);

  // Make the 'x' in the corner remove the section it's contained within
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
      $(this).parents('section').remove();
  });

  // Reset form fields
  $name.val('');
  $species.val('Dog');
  $notes.val('');

  } else {
    let br = document.createElement('BR');
    let alertMessage = document.createTextNode('Please read the terms and conditions.');
    let span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    span.style.color = '#FF0000';
    span.appendChild(alertMessage);
    let termsLabel = document.getElementById('termsLabel');
    termsLabel.appendChild(br);
    termsLabel.appendChild(span);
    alertMessage = '';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `innerHTML` DOM element property to clean up node's content:

```
else {
    let br = document.createElement('BR');
    let alertMessage = document.createTextNode('Please read the terms and conditions.');
    let span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    span.style.color = '#FF0000';
    span.appendChild(alertMessage);
    let termsLabel = document.getElementById('termsLabel');
    termsLabel.innerHTML = ''; // this removes previous content of the node including all it's children
    termsLabel.appendChild(br);
    termsLabel.appendChild(span);
  }
```

But I would use just:

```
else {
  let termsLabel = document.getElementById('termsLabel');
  termsLabel.innerHTML = 'Please read the terms and conditions.';
}
```

And all styles for `termsLabel` element should be declared via CSS in a way like

```
#termsLabel {
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: red;
}
```

**UPD** Here's the fiddler satisfying new requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/yy1z75e7/2/

Comment: dhilt, thank you for the update. I tried this, and it ends up taking the termsLabel out, which I need. I need the alert to pop up under the termsLabel. I thought creating the alertMessage, and then appending it as a child to the termsLabel would do, but it ends up just recreating the error message over and over. I tried setting alertMessage.innerHTML = ' '; and the same behavior happens.

Comment: I believe, the issue you are trying to resolve is pretty easy, and I could fix it if you would create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/) or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or whatever demo for it.

Comment: I updated your fiddle a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/yy1z75e7/2/ since I still think that it's not a good idea to create node instead of manipulating a visibility via css. And no content is being changed anymore, just visibility. Also I improved the UX around Terms checkbox clicking. Is there something that you want to do from this point?

Comment: My friend, you're awesome. That is all I needed to do! Thanks again.

Comment: You may do an upvote for my answer. Good luck and come back with new questions!

Comment: Yes of course. I always forget to do that! I will be back for sure! Happy coding mate!

Answer (score 1):

Clear the element before appending the alert messages

```
termsLabel.innerHTML = '';
termsLabel.appendChild(br);
termsLabel.appendChild(span);
```

Or when creating the span give it a class or id, and then check termsLabel to see if it already has the span. If it doesn't then create it, otherwise don't do anything.

```
//cache this so you don't keep needing to call it over and over
let termsLabel = document.getElementById('termsLabel');

//querySelector() will return null if the span isn't in termsLabel
if(!termsLabel.querySelector('.errorMessage')){
  let br = document.createElement('BR');
  let alertMessage = document.createTextNode('Please read the terms and conditions.');
  let span = document.createElement('SPAN');
  span.style.color = '#FF0000';
  span.classList.add("errorMessage");
  span.appendChild(alertMessage);
  termsLabel.appendChild(br);
  termsLabel.appendChild(span);
}
```

This also gives you the ability to remove the message as well

```
document.querySelector('.errorMessage').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the button, and the code in the else clause executes, you are creating new elements. What you want to do instead is to check if the element, termsLabel lets say, is created first, and if it is then change its innerHtml or text values, and if it isn't then create the element instead.